# Pattern matching: constants and rigid type variables

Tags: haskell

A beginner's question.

I'm trying to understand how pattern matching works with constants.

```
-- myF :: [a] -> [a]
myF ('p':'r':'e':_) = "Prefix"
myF (x:xs) = x:xs
myF [] = []
```

This compiles and runs fine.
However, if I uncomment the line that tries to specify the function's type, it fails with Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type` Char'
`a' is a rigid type variable bound by
the type signature for:
myF :: forall a. [a] -> [a]

https://godbolt.org/z/51oMGW4Ev

If I understand this error correctly, it complains that the function should work with any type, but the specialization for "pre" constant can only return String?

Does that mean that you can't "specialize" functions on constants of different types?

I.e.

```
myF ('p':'r':'e':_) = "Prefix"
myF (1:2:3:[]) = 0:[]
```

Again, not that this would be useful for anything, but just hoping to understand the pattern matching mechanism.

Thank you.

Comment: Note that the type variable `a` in `[a] -> [a]` is a parameter filled in by the caller, whose value is unknown to the function itself. That signature is short for `forall a. [a] -> [a]`, where `forall a.` is akin to `<A>` in Java or`template<class A>` in C++. Unlike those languages, parametricity means that Haskell requires you to spell out any additional constraints you use, such as `Num a` (a typeclass constraint), or in this case you could technically say `a ~ Char` (an equality constraint).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haskell is designed so that it is possible to run it without keeping type information at runtime (in the vast majority of cases). There are good reasons for that, one of which is optimization (less data to be kept and passed around).

That is, when we call a function

```
f :: [a] -> ...
```

`f` does not receive any information on the type `a`. Roughly, `f` is passed a bunch of "bits" that represent a list of something, but `f` does not know if the bits encoding the list elements are representing integers, characters, or anything else.

Indeed, it is possible (in theory, at least) that the list `[0,1]` has the exact bit-level representation as the list `[False, True]`, so `f` can not distinguish between them. Coherently, we can't write

```
f [0,1] = [1,1,1]
f [x,y] = [x]  -- would match against [False, True]
...
```

The pattern matching rule is quite simple: we can only match against known types. So, we can match against `Int`s, `(String, Bool)`, as so on. We can't match against a type variable like `a` since we don't know what that is. We can also partly match against `[a]` but no deeper than the list "level": we can match against `x:y:z:[]` since that only inspects the list, but `x:True:[]` would also match against a value of type `a`, so that's out.

Note that there are some advanced features of modern Haskell (like GADTs and `Typeable`) that can be used to keep some of type information at runtime, so that a similar form of the "forbidden `f`" seen above becomes possible. Since you wrote you are a beginner, I'd recommend you ignore these advanced features for now. Stick to the basics first, and once you are familiar with them you can then dig into the more complex features.

Comment: Do GADTs really keep type information for runtime? I thought the constructors were runtime tagged like everything else, and any extra type information you get out of them is still at compile time.

Comment: @amalloy No additional type information is kept at runtime beyond the constructor tag, as you mention. Still, GADTs can be used to store type information in that tag. Normally, if we have `g :: a -> ...` we can't pattern match on that `a`, but if we have `g :: MyGADT a -> a -> ...` then pattern matching on `a` might become possible (which is what OP asked). Singletons could also be used to pass the GADT using a type class `g :: Sing a => a -> ...` which is IMO not that far from `Typeable a => a -> ...`.

Comment: Thank you for trying to explain this to me. I'm still confused though :(
I'll ask a few clarifying questions if I may.
I come from C++ where not having runtime type info is the norm, so I understand the part about not wanting to store type info at runtime.
However, something like what I showed here is possible in C++ using templates.

Isn't ```[Char] -> [Char]``` just a special case of ```[a] -> [a]``` ?
And so, if I specify the function as [a] -> [a], it should also work for [Char]?
Note that the above compiles and runs fine. Only if I try to specify the function type the issues arise.

Comment: In C++, a template function is not fully compiled until the template arguments are known (at instantiation time). C++ also allows template specializations and SFINAE. Haskell instead fully compiles (and type checks) the polymorphic (generic) function at definition time -- there is no "instantiation time" later on. C++ would allow the equivalent of `f1 :: a->a->Bool ; f x y = (x==y)` because of SFINAE, while Haskell rejects it requiring one to use `f2 :: Eq a => a->a->Bool` instead. In Haskell, the definition of `f1` has to work for all types `a`, in C++ not so (SFINAE).

Comment: I see. I guess I did think of Haskell functions' genericity in terms of the templates. Thank you for giving the examples. It probably also mean that Haskell does not have to generate different code for functions that deal with arguments of different types?

Comment: @AndyVenikov Exactly, there's only one function. You can even write silly things like `f ::  Int -> [a] -> Int ; f 0 xs = length xs ; f n xs = f (n-1) [xs]` which, when called as in `f 100 [True]` will recurse until `f 0 [[[...[True]....]]]` before returning 1. This function would be impossible to compile by instantiating templates (as in C++ or Rust) since we need `f` on `n` types `[Bool], [[Bool]], ...` but `n` is an unknown argument at compilation time. There are pros and cons to instantiating templates (as in C++) vs one-size-fits-all (as in Haskell, Java, ...).

Comment: @AndyVenikov In Haskell, when you do need to have distinct implementations `f :: a -> ...` for distinct types `a`, you use typeclasses. E.g. `(==) :: Eq a => a->a->Bool` must be implemented for each type `a`, so it's done using a typeclass `Eq`. Here we do have multiple instances of the function, but only as many as the `instance`s that occur in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You use `('p': …)` here or in canonical form `((:)) 'p' (…))`, this uses the `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` data constructor. But the first item is `'p'`, this is a pattern for a `Char` value. This thus means that the first parameter of the `(:)` data constructor is a `Char`, and hence the type of the `('p': …)` is a `[Char]`, so a list of `Char`s. The type of the items is thus can not have *any* type `a`, but only `Char`s.

This thus means that the type of the pattern is `[Char]` or `String` (which is just an alias of `[Char]`).

The return type is also `[Char]` (or `String`), since `"Prefix"` is a `String`, the same holds for `x : xs` since `x` is a `Char` and `xs` is a list of `Char`s:

```
myF :: String -> String
myF ('p' : 'r' : 'e' : _) = "Prefix"
myF (x : xs) = x : xs
myF [] = []
```

this can be shortened to:

```
myF :: String -> String
myF ('p' : 'r' : 'e' : _) = "Prefix"
myF xs = xs
```

You can not implement a function:

```
myF ('p':'r':'e':_) = "Prefix"
myF (1:2:3:[]) = 0:[]
```

since the first clause requires that the input types has type `[Char]`, whereas the second one has a type `(Eq a, Num a) => [a]`.

Comment: Thank you. You write: "The type of the items is thus can not have any type a, but only Chars." But isn't it only true for that specific function instance that was pattern-matched? Couldn't other matches for this function operate on other types? I thought that functions in Haskell were generic by default and could operate with different types?